# Take a list of ascii strings from a file and hash them using python threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, concurrency

How can I do this in a more performant way? I'm concerned that throwing the data in a queue like this is defeating the purpose of `yield` from the `open()` and also how about handling the shared reference to file handle?

```
import hashlib
import sys
from threading import Thread
import queue


class HashWorker(Thread):

    def __init__(self, queue, fp_out):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.fp_out = fp_out

    def run(self):
        while True:
            password = self.queue.get()
            try:
                hash_threaded(password, self.fp_out)
            finally:
                self.queue.task_done()


def main(argv):

    if sanitize(argv) is False:
        return -1

    # fp = open(argv[1], "r")
    fp_out = open("sha256hashes.txt", "a+")

    myqueue = queue.Queue()

    for x in range(8):
        worker = HashWorker(myqueue, fp_out)
        worker.daemon = True
        worker.start()

    for l in open(argv[1], "r"):
        myqueue.put(l)

    myqueue.join()
    print("Done.")
    fp_out.close()


def sanitize(argv):
    if len(argv) != 2:
        print("USAGE: {} filename.txt".format(argv[0]))
        return False
    return True


def hash_threaded(password, fp_out):
    line_bytes = bytes(password, "ascii")
    output_line = hashlib.sha256(line_bytes).hexdigest()
    fp_out.write("{}\n".format(output_line))
    #  print(".", end='')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```